# why can't I get the value and show it in a input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the quarter of the year and if some condition is meet, put a specific value into a textBox.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery().on('keyup', function (event) {
        var month = (new Date()).getMonth();
        var quarter = (Math.ceil(month / 3));

        var adCov='';
        if (quarter===1) {
             adCov = jQuery(".A1").val() / jQuery(".Q1").val();
        }
        else
        if (quarter === 2) {
             adCov = jQuery(".A2").val() / jQuery(".Q2").val();
            }
        else
        if (quarter === 3) {
             adCov = jQuery(".A3").val() / jQuery(".Q3").val();
                }
        else
        if (quarter === 4) {
             adCov = jQuery(".A4").val() / jQuery(".Q4").val();
        }

        //document.getElementsByClassName("adCov").val() = adCov;
        $(".adCov").val(adCov);
    });
  });
..................................................................
```

the table below is in a loop:

```
  '<td class="bg-success number">< input type = "text" name = "total" 
 class="" /> <input type=""text  class="adCov"/> </td>' +
```

Comment: Can you please include html content too in your question @ladi . because i Cant identify what is `A1`,`A2` etc from this

Comment: Why is this tagged with `ajax` and `asp.net-mvc`? There's nothing in the example that would justify those tags.

Comment: the A1, A2 A3, ... are class names of some <td>

Comment: This `< input type = "text" name = "total" 
 class="" /> <input type=""text class="adCov"/>` produces invalid markup

Comment: `jQuery().on('keyup',` -- I'm not even sure when or if that will run, since there's no selector. Also, all of those `.val()` will only run for the first elements in the DOM that have that class.

Comment: is `jQuery().on('keyup', function (event) {}` event is working fine? for which selector it will worjk?